# Should a subdirectory or subdomain also be moved to https?

Tags: seo, google-search, https, ranking, traffic

Many have reported a loss of traffic when moving from `http` to `https`. The reasons for this are not clear.

Could NOT shifting a subdirectory or subfolder to https be a reason for the loss of ranking of the main site (now served with a SSL)?

Comment: @Josip-ivic Thank you.
I made the switch from http to https. It was quite smooth but for 8 days, 40 days into the transfer, I lost all search traffic. Then it recovered as abruptly as it went away. From a Matt Cutts video I understand this is normal as it takes time for page rank to pass from the old page to the new one via a 301.
Reg. the second part
I have three sites site.com,section.site.com, site.com/folder

site.com is now https. Earlier the /folder was http but I realised the same ssl can be extended to it and did so. 
But the section.site.com is still http. Is this okay?

Answer (score 1):

> Many have reported a loss of traffic when moving from http to https. The reasons for this are not clear.

Yes they are clear. Moving your website from HTTP to HTTPS is very much like migrating your website to a new URL structure, or even moving to a brand new domain.

If you properly 301 redirect to the correct protocol (http to https) there will be very little disruption. You may get some short-term movement to your rankings but you will bounce back to where you would have been.

There is absolutely no reason why making the switch would cause loss of ranking in the end.

> Could NOT shifting a subdirectory or subfolder to https be a reason
>   for the loss of ranking of the main site (now served with a SSL)?

//this part with shifting a subdirectory or subfolder you need to clarify a little bit in your question. What subdirectory or subfolder? You transfered to https or not? Give a example. But short answer is that you didn't migrate everything to https if you think that it has to do with some subfolders. (I don't know what you mean in this part clearly)

Comment: The question is not clear. YOu are right about that! If we assume that just a directory is moved to HTTPS, not sure how that would be done by the OP, however, making that assumption, if you are looking at Google Analytics, Search Console, and other Google products, then yes. There would be a drop in traffic as seen through these tools. The OP would have to create another property with HTTPS to see the traffic. Maybe that is what the OP is referring to?? Cheers!!

Comment: i don't know, I'll let him to put more details in question so we can deal with specific problem. This second part is very unclear, so I made assumption,

Comment: You did great! Cheers!!